# Can I have a dictionary with same-name keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I need to have a dictionary which might have same names for some keys and return a list of values when referencing the key in that case.

For example

```
print mydict['key']
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: No, but you can use mydict = {'key':[1,2,3,4]}

Answer (score 18):

For consistency, you should have the dictionary map keys to lists (or sets) of values, of which some can be empty. There is a nice idiom for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)

d["key"].add(...)
```

(A `defaultdict` is like a normal dictionary, but if a key is missing it will call the argument you passed in when you instantiated it and use the result as the default value. So this will automatically create an empty set of values if you ask for a key which isn't already present.)

---

If you need the object to look more like a dictionary (i.e. to set a value by `d["key"] = ...`) you can do the following. **But** this is probably a bad idea, because it goes against the normal Python syntax, and is likely to come back and bite you later. Especially if someone else has to maintain your code.

```
class Multidict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Multidict, self).__init__(set)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, (self.default_factory)): # self.default_factory is `set`
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
        else:
            self[key].append(value)
```

<sub>I haven't tested this.</sub>

Comment: The code in the example (Multidict) doesn't work and I am not sure you can make it work by deriving from defaultdict. The problem is that `self[key]` calls `setitem` if there is no such item (that is what defaultdict adds on top of plain dict). And it is impossible to distinguish who is calling setitem: user or defaultdict internals.

Comment: @Andrey possible to distinguish who is calling setitem with rewriting __missing__ method

Answer (score 11):

You can also try `paste.util.multidict.MultiDict`

```
$ easy_install Paste
```

Then:

```
from paste.util.multidict import MultiDict
d = MultiDict()
d.add('a', 1)
d.add('a', 2)
d.add('b', 3)
d.mixed()
>>> {'a': [1, 2], 'b': 3}
d.getall('a')
>>> [1, 2]
d.getall('b')
>>> [3]
```

Web frameworks like Pylons are using this library to handle HTTP query string/post data, which can have same-name keys.

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
myDict = {'key': []}
```

Then during runtime:

```
if newKey in myDict:
    myDict[newKey].append(value)
else:
    myDict[newKey] = [value]
```

Edited as per @Ben's comment:

```
myDict = {}
myDict.setdefault(newKey, []).append(value)
```

Comment: Its' more idiomatic to day myDict.setdefault(newKey, []).append(value)

Answer (score 3):

This is an ideal place to use a defaultdict object from the collections library

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(set)
mydict['key'] += set([1,2,3,4])
mydict['key'] += set([4,5,6])

print(mydict['key'])
```

returns [1,2,3,4,5,6]

In the case where a key is referenced that has not been implicitly assigned, an empty set is returned.

```
print(mydict['bad_key'])
```

returns []

Using *setdefault* on a dict from the standard library would require a significant change in your syntax when assigning values and can get rather messy. I've never used Multidict, but it also looks like a significant change in the way assignments are made. Using this method, you simply assume that there may already be a value associated with this key in the dictionary and slightly modify your assignment operator by using the '+=' operator when assigning key values.

FYI - I am a big fan of using the NoneType as the default which results in any access of an invalid key returning None. This behaves properly in most cases including iterating and json dumps, but for your specific need the default should be of type *set* unless you want to enable having duplicate values stored in the key. Then use a *list*. In fact, anytime you have a homogenous dictionary the default should be of that type.

```
mydict = defaultdict(lambda: None)
```

Comment: Note that `dict.get` from standard `dict` already returns `None` as a default, so `defaultdict` seems a bit overkill if that's the only thing you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsatisfied with all the proposed solutions, so this is my solution. This is for Python 3. Code is below.

## EXAMPLES

(code is below)

```
>>> a = MultiDict({0: [0]})
>>> a
MultiDict({0: [0]})
>>> a[0] = (1, 7)
>>> a
MultiDict({0: [1, 7]})
>>> a.add(0, 2)
>>> a
MultiDict({0: [1, 7, 2]})
>>> a.add(1, 2)
>>> a
MultiDict({0: [1, 7, 2], 1: [2]})
>>> a.getfirst(0)
1
>>> a.getfirst(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 61, in getfirst
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in __getitem__
KeyError: 3
>>> len(a)
2
>>> tuple(a.items())
((0, [1, 7, 2]), (1, [2]))
>>> tuple(a.values())
([1, 7, 2], [2])
>>> a.get(0)
[1, 7, 2]
>>> tuple(a.multiitems())
((0, 1), (0, 7), (0, 2), (1, 2))
>>> tuple(a.multikeys())
(0, 0, 0, 1)
>>> tuple(a.multivalues())
(1, 7, 2, 2)
>>> a.remove(0, 1)
>>> a
MultiDict({0: [7, 2], 1: [2]})
>>> a.remove(3, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 53, in remove
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in __getitem__
KeyError: 3
>>> a.remove(0, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 53, in remove
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 56, in remove
ValueError: No element with value 5 for key 0
>>> b = MultiDict({0: [7, 2], 1: [2]})
>>> b == a
True
>>> c = MultiDict(a)
>>> c
MultiDict({0: [7, 2], 1: [2]})
>>> d = MultiDict({0: 0})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 30, in __init__
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 33, in __init__
TypeError: Values must be iterables, found 'int' for key 0
>>> a.pop(0)
[7, 2]
>>> a
MultiDict({1: [2]})
>>> c.popitem()
(0, [7, 2])
>>> c.setdefault(0, [1])
[1]
>>> c
MultiDict({0: [1], 1: [2]})
>>> c.setdefault(0, [2])
[1]
>>> c
MultiDict({0: [1], 1: [2]})
>>> c.setdefault(3)
[]
>>> c
MultiDict({0: [1], 1: [2], 3: []})
>>> c.getfirst(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 61, in getfirst
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 63, in getfirst
IndexError: No values in key 3
>>> c.clear()
>>> c
MultiDict({})
>>> c.update(b)
>>> c
MultiDict({0: [7, 2], 1: [2]})
>>> d = c.copy()
>>> d == c
True
>>> id(d) == id(c)
False
>>> MultiDict.fromkeys((0, 1), [5])
MultiDict({0: [5], 1: [5]})
>>> MultiDict.fromkeys((0, 1))
MultiDict({0: [], 1: []})
```

## CODE

```
try:
    from collections.abc import MutableMapping
except ImportError:  # python < 3.3
    from collections import MutableMapping

class MultiDict(MutableMapping):
    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, seq, value=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if value is None:
            v = []
        else:
            v = value
        
        return cls(dict.fromkeys(seq, v, *args, **kwargs))
    
    
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self._dict[k] = list(v)
    
    
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self._dict[k]
    
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for k in self._dict:
            yield k
    
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._dict = dict(*args, **kwargs)
        
        for k, v in self._dict.items():
            try:
                self._dict[k] = list(v)
            except TypeError:
                err_str = "Values must be iterables, found '{t}' for key {k}"
                raise TypeError(err_str.format(k=k, t=type(v).__name__))
    
    
    def __delitem__(self, k):
        del self._dict[k]
    
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)
    
    
    def add(self, k, v):
        if not k in self:
            self[k] = []
        
        self[k].append(v)
    
    
    def remove(self, k, v):
        try:
            self[k].remove(v)
        except ValueError:
            err_str = "No element with value {v} for key {k}"
            raise ValueError(err_str.format(v=v, k=k))
    
    
    def getfirst(self, k):
        try:
            res = self[k][0]
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError("No values in key {k}".format(k=k))
        
        return self[k][0]
    
    
    def multiitems(self):
        for k, v in self.items():
            for vv in v:
                yield (k, vv)
    
    
    def multikeys(self):
        for k, v in self.items():
            for vv in v:
                yield k
    
    
    def multivalues(self):
        for v in self.values():
            for vv in v:
                yield vv
    
    
    def setdefault(self, k, default=None):
        if default is None:
            def_val = []
        else:
            def_val = default
        
        if k not in self:
            self[k] = def_val
        
        return self[k]
    
    
    def copy(self):
        return self.__class__(self)
    
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            self.__class__.__name__ + 
            "({{{body}}})".format(body=self._dict)
        )
```

## SOME VERBOSE EXPLAINATION

For simplicity, the constructor is the same as `dict`. All values passed to the constructor, or assigned directly to a key, **must** be iterables.

All the values of my `MultiDict` are lists, even if value is only one. This is to avoid confusion.

I added also a `remove` method to delete a single entry from the `MultiDict`. Furthermore I added a `multiitems`, that iters over the couple (key, value) over all the values of the dictionary. `multikeys` and `multivalues` are similar.

## ALTERNATIVES

You can also use [multidict](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/) (keys can be only strings, included in `aiohttp`), [Werkzeug](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict)  or [WebOb](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/api/multidict.html) (slow).

Comment: aiohttp's MultiDict (which is a separate PyPI module called `multidict`) only supports strings as keys, not arbitrary hashables. WebOb's MultiDict stores (key,value) pairs in a list, so all operations are O(n). Werkzeug's MultiDict is the only one really worthy of the name. It uses a dict of lists, so its asymptotic performance is reasonable, but it's pure Python so the constant factors are probably fairly high.

Comment: @benrg: `multidict` uses only strings because it's tailored for the web. About Werkzeug, please remeber the concept of Premature Optimization. 

Anyway, I'll edit the alternatives section.

Answer (score 1):

```
def toMultiDict(items):
    def insertMulti(d, kv):
        k, v = kv
        d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
        return d
    return reduce(insertMulti, [{}] + items)
```

should create a dict from key to a list of values:

```
In [28]: toMultiDict(zip([1,2,1], [4,5,6]))
Out[28]: {1: [4, 6], 2: [5]}
```

I couldn't put insertMulti into a lambda, because the lambda needs to return the dict again.