# How to sum coupled values in a dict-like structure in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key, tuples

I have an xlsx that I'm parsing with `openpyxl`.

Column A is Product Name, Column B is revenue, and I want to extract each pair of prouct-revenue values into a `dict`. Were there no duplicate products, it would simply be a matter of the creating a dict by mapping `ws.columns` appropriately.

The problem is, there are multiple entries for some (but not all) products. For these, I need to sum the values in question, and just return a single key for those products (as for the rest). So if my revenue spreadsheet contains the following:

[image]

I want to **sum the values** of Revenue for Banana before returning the dict. The desired outcome then is:

```
{'Banana': 7.2, 'Apple': 1.7, 'Pear': 6.2, 'Kiwi': 1.2}
```

The following would work OK were there no duplicates:

```
revenue{}
i = 0;
for product in ws.columns[0]:
    revenue[product.value] = ws.columns[1][i].value
    i+=1
```

But obviously it breaks down when it encounters duplicates. I could try using a [MultiDict()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6815061/1389110), which will give a structure from which I can perform the addition and create my final `dict`:

```
d = MultiDict()
for i in range(len(ws.columns[1])):
        d.add(ws.columns[0][i].value,ws.columns[1][i].value)
```

This leaves me with a `MultiDict`, which itself is actually a **list of tuples**, and it all gets a tad convoluted. Is there a neater or standard-library way of achieving the same-key-multiple-times data structure? What about employing `zip()`? Doesn't necessarily have to be dict-like. I just need to be able to create a `dict` from it (and then perform the addition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be close to what you want, assuming you can transform your data to a list of key-value tuples:

```
list_key_value_tuples = [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("A", 3)]

d = {}
for key, value in list_key_value_tuples:
    d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + value

> print d
{'A': 4, 'B': 2}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Given that a MultiDict actually resembles your `list_key_value` above (namely, a list of tuples), I chanced running your suggestion with the MutliDict as `list_key_value`. It resulted in *ValueError: too many values to unpack*. So I reworked the extraction of values to put them in a list of tuples like you have, and it worked. Elegantly done paljenczy, thank you.

Comment: You can initialize **d** as `defaultdict(int)` to get rid of the expression `d.get(key, 0)`

Comment: That's right. As I see it, it is a matter of personal taste to use one or the other - I prefer the `get` method as it tells exactly what it does.

Answer (score 1):

`collections.defaultdict` was made for this type of use case.

```
>>> 
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(float)
>>> p = [('Kiwi', 1.2), ('Banana', 3.2), ('Pear', 6.2), ('Banana', 2.3), ('Apple', 1.7), ('Banana', 1.7)]
>>> for k,v in p:
    d[k] += v


>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {'Kiwi': 1.2, 'Pear': 6.2, 'Banana': 7.2, 'Apple': 1.7})
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `length` of second column is *less* than the first one; one can simply group rows by value in the first column and sum the rest like the following:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

rows = izip_longest(ws.columns[0], ws.columns[1], fillvalue=0)

result = dict((k, sum((g[1] for g in v))) for k, v in groupby(rows, itemgetter(0)))
```

Comment: Columns lengths are equal, but I'll try your approach anyway. Thanks.

Comment: if column lengths are equal then it doesn't matter. the code above breaks only if first column's length is greater.