# How to identify "keys" of a tuple/list of 3-item tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key, tuples

Given a table of revenue values thus:

[image]

A key point to note (and the core of my question) is the the brand name will **almost** always, but not always, contain the corresponding product name. In the case of last Banana entry, it doesn't.

I will extract a `dict` of **Brand<->Revenue** pairs, fist accounting for those brands that have multiple entries, and summing in those cases, using the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31197541/1389110). So:

```
revenuePerBrandDict = {}
brandRevenueTuples = []
i=0
for brand in ourTab.columns[1][1:-1]: # ignore first (zeroth) and last row
    brandRevenueTuples.append((campaign.value, round(ourTab.columns[3][i].value,2)))
    i+=1
for key, value in brandRevenueTuples:
        revenuePerBrandDict[key] = revenuePerBrandDict.get(key, 0) + value
```

I will then cross-reference the keys and values in this dict to each dict in (dict of banana *expenses*, dict of kiwi *expenses* etc.), and subtract expenses from revenue, item per item. These dicts will be extracted from banana table, kiwi table etc. that look like this:

[image]

If the brand name *always* contained the product name in the revenue table, then in order to compile an appropriate collection of revenue values for comparison with the Banana expenses dict, for example, I would just extract all those brands whose name contained 'Banana', and for matching keys in the Banana expenses dict, perform the extraction on their values.

But it doesn't, so **I need another way of knowing that in the Revenue dict, 'OtherBrand' is a Banana.** (In the *Banana* dict, I already know it is a Banana, because it came from the Banana table). Instead of extracting a `dict` of Brand<->Revenue pairs, I could extract a list or tuple of (tuples of (Product, Brand, Revenue)), and now we have the additional information provided by the *Product* column. But since a tuple doesn't have the concept of a key, how do I iterate across this new collection, extracting revenue per tuple in the desired way (i.e. with recognition that that *OtherBrand* is a Banana etc.)

Comment: The title doesn't really align with the problem, but I couldn't think of a better way of concisely summarizing the problem ...

Comment: *You* must define which field is a logical key, or supply a mapping function that can build a key for each tuple. That is, after application of 'key function' the results is a sequence of `(key(t), t)` where the first item is now guaranteed to be the key. If the question is then about *grouping* - ie. ending up with a sequence or dictionary of `(k, list_of_t)`, where k is distinct - then it's about grouping and naught to do with determining the key which again .. *you* must do.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes you're right, it's more of a grouping issue than an issue of determining/selecting a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fruits as keys and group the brands:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

with open("in.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    next(r) # skip header
    # fruite will be keys, values will be dicts
    # with brands as keys  and running totals for rev as values
    d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for fruit, brand, rev in r:
        d[fruit][brand] += float(rev)
```

Which using your input outputs:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(dict(d))
{'Apple': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'CrunchApple': 1.7}),
 'Banana': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'BananaBrand': 4.0,   'OtherBrand': 3.2}),
 'Kiwi': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'NZKiwi': 1.2}),
 'Pear': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'PearShaped': 6.2})
```

You can then subtract the expenses using the keys.

Using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) life is even easier you can groupby and sum:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("in.csv")

print(df.groupby(("A","B")).sum())
```

Output:

```
A      B               
Apple  CrunchApple  1.7
Banana BananaBrand  4.0
       OtherBrand   3.2
Kiwi   NZKiwi       1.2
Pear   PearShaped   6.2
```

Or get the groups by fruit  and brand:

```
groups = df.groupby(["A","B"])

print(groups.get_group(('Banana', 'OtherBrand')))

print(groups.get_group(('Banana', 'BananaBrand')))
```

Comment: It's an xlsx and the data I need is in the second tab, so I'm using `openpyxl`. Will try to port your suggestion over. Not too sure of the significance of `next()` and `lambda` here (though this is the first time I've come across next(), and I only began using lambda today.

Comment: @Pyderman, it just skips the header, we don't want the column names. The logic will be exactly the same. Just extract each fruit, brand and rev from each row. The `lambda: defaultdict(int)` is used as the object passed to the defaultdict must be callable so it allows us to specify that we will be using an int/float as the value

Comment: Thanks Padraic. Successfully mapped your defaultdict approach to openpyxl. Working nicely. Have yet to use pandas, I must check it  out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to group your data from the first table by product type. I suggest a dictionary where the key is the product type and the value is a list of tuples `[(brand, revenue),(..., ...)]`.

Then, for each product type in the dictionary, you can easily pull out the list of brands for that product and, if needed, make a  new dictionary containing lists of 3-tuples `(brand, revenue, expenses)`.

Comment: Seem reasonable. Just so I'm clear before I try this: you intend *each value* of each item in the dict to be a list of brand-revenue tuples, correct?