# How to concatenate or combine two defaultdicts of defaultdicts that have overlapping keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key, defaultdict

Working with the suggestion provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31214462/1389110), and having **two** revenue tables to have to extract from (containing the same fruits but different brands):

[image]

[image]

I end of with two `defaultdicts` of `defaultdicts`:

**d1**

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x105dd42a8>, {u'Kiwi': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'NZKiwi': 1.2}), u'Pear': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'PearShaped': 6.2}), u'Banana': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'BananaBrand': 4.0, u'OtherBrand': 3.2}), u'Apple': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'CrunchApple': 1.7})})
```

**d2**

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x105dd41b8>, {u'Kiwi': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'n': 1.2}), u'Pear': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'p': 6.2}), u'Banana': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'b': 4.0, u'o': 3.2}), u'Apple': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'a': 1.7})})
```

Assuming for argument's sake that I cannot combine the two tables before the above processing, how do I now combine these defaultdicts such that the keys (the fruit types) are maintained, yet their respective values get concatenated, per key? In other words, how do I end up with the following:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x105dd41b8>, {u'Kiwi': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'n': 1.2, u'NZKiwi': 1.2}), u'Pear': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'p': 6.2, u'PearShaped': 6.2}), u'Banana': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'b': 4.0, u'o': 3.2, u'BananaBrand': 4.0, u'OtherBrand': 3.2}}), u'Apple': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'a': 1.7, u'CrunchApple': 1.7})})
```

Actually it doesn't necessarily have to take that structure - really what I need is something from which I can extract the individual brand-amount pairs, **per product**. So end is results is a dict for Banana containing its 4 brand-amount pairs, another dict for Kiwi containing its two brand-amount pairs etc.

### UPDATE: I could do the following, but there is surely a cleaner way??

```
BananaDict = {}
KiwiDict ={}
AppleDict = {}
PearDict = {}

for k, v in d1.iteritems():
    if k == 'Banana':
        BananaDict.update(v)
    elif k == 'Kiwi'
    etc.
    etc.
```

then repeat the above for d2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a simple for loop , example -

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int, {u'Kiwi': defaultdict(int, {u'NZKiwi': 1.2}), u'Pear': defaultdict(int, {u'PearShaped': 6.2}), u'Banana': defaultdict(int, {u'BananaBrand': 4.0, u'OtherBrand': 3.2}), u'Apple': defaultdict(int, {u'CrunchApple': 1.7})})
>>> d1 = defaultdict(int, {u'Kiwi': defaultdict(int, {u'n': 1.2}), u'Pear': defaultdict(int, {u'p': 6.2}), u'Banana': defaultdict(int, {u'b': 4.0, u'o': 3.2}), u'Apple': defaultdict(int, {u'a': 1.7})})
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     v.update(d1[k])
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Banana': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'o': 3.2, 'OtherBrand': 3.2, 'BananaBrand': 4.0, 'b': 4.0}), 'Pear': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'PearShaped': 6.2, 'p': 6.2}), 'Kiwi': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'NZKiwi': 1.2, 'n': 1.2}), 'Apple': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 1.7, 'CrunchApple': 1.7})})
```

Comment: I knew it would involve a loop and `update()`, I just didn't know exactly how. Nicely done, Anand, thank you.

Comment: The problem here is that what if d1 had a key that didnt exist in d. You need to add it to that.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the other answer didnt account for the case where the new dictionary had a key that the original dictionary didnt have.

```
def merge_defaultdicts(d,d1):
    for k,v in d1.items():
        if (k in d):
            d[k].update(d1[k])
        else:
            d[k] = d1[k]
    return d
```