# Merge list of dict into one dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list of dicts in python.

```
[
{
"US": {
"Intial0": 12.515
},
{
"GE": {
"Intial0": 11.861
}
},
{
"US": {
"Final0": 81.159
}
},
{
"GE": {
"Final0": 12.9835
}
}
]
```

I want the final list of dicts as

```
[{"US": {"Initial0":12.515, "Final0": 81.159}}, {"GE": {"Initial0": 11.861, "Final0": 12.9835}}]
```

I am struggling with this from quite some time . Any help?

Comment: Why do you want that, instead of a single dict of dicts? `{"US": {...}, "GE": {...}}`?

Comment: Related [How to merge multiple dicts with same key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key)

Comment: Rohit, what have you tried?  Have you looked at using update?  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm

Comment: fredtantini, check out these previous posts.  Here are 2 of them:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813564/python-have-dictionary-with-same-name-keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Python's [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lod = [
    {"US": {"Intial0": 12.515}},
    {"GE": {"Intial0": 11.861}},
    {"US": {"Final0": 81.159}},
    {"GE": {"Final0": 12.9835}}]

output = defaultdict(dict)

for d in lod:
    output[d.keys()[0]].update(d.values()[0])

print output
```

For the data given, this would display the following:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'GE': {'Intial0': 11.861, 'Final0': 12.9835}, 'US': {'Intial0': 12.515, 'Final0': 81.159}})
```

Or you could convert it back to a standard Python dictionary with `print dict(output)` giving:

```
{'GE': {'Intial0': 11.861, 'Final0': 12.9835}, 'US': {'Intial0': 12.515, 'Final0': 81.159}}
```

Answer (score 0):

list1=[{"US": {"Intial0": 12.515}},{"GE": {"Intial0": 11.861}},{"US": {"Final0": 81.159}},{"GE": {"Final0": 12.9835}}]

dict_US={}
dict_GE={}
for dict_x in list1:
        if dict_x.keys()==['US']:
                dict_US.update(dict_x["US"])
        if dict_x.keys()==['GE']:
                dict_GE.update(dict_x["GE"])
list2=[{"US":dict_US},{"GE":dict_GE}]
print list2