# How to merge two dictionaries without clobbering

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries and I want to combine them.

```
dict1 = {'abc': {'test1': 123}}
dict2 = {'abc': {'test2': 456}}
```

I want to end up with

```
{'abc': {'test1': 123, 'test2': 456}}
```

if `dict2 = {'abc': 100}` then I would want:

```
{'abc' 100}
```

I tried `dict1.update(dict2)` but that gave me `{'abc': {'test2': 456}}`

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What would be the output is the value for 'abc' in dict2 is not a dictionary?

Comment: How your merge should act when elements from two dictionaries have different type values under the same key?

Comment: @Tino: The later should over write, good question.

Comment: @RaySteam: if dict2 = {'abc': 100} I would want {'abc': 100}, if the are dicts then merge

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have a dictionary with same-name keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813564/can-i-have-a-dictionary-with-same-name-keys)

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: @ Alexander Cécile: I have created a caching module that I need to update in real time, I don't know what is going to be added to the cache at any time so the cache must be able to to preform crud operations. If you are interested have a look have a look at my cache module. If there is a better way to do this please let me know. https://pastebin.com/E1Wk22Cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you could do the following:

```
def recursive_update(d1, d2):
    """Updates recursively the dictionary values of d1"""

    for key, value in d2.items():
        if key in d1 and isinstance(d1[key], dict) and isinstance(value, dict):
            recursive_update(d1[key], value)
        else:
            d1[key] = value


dict1 = {'abc': {'test1': 123}}
dict2 = {'abc': {'test2': 456}}

recursive_update(dict1, dict2)

print(dict1)
```

**Output**

```
{'abc': {'test1': 123, 'test2': 456}}
```

Note that the recursion only works for values that are dictionaries. For example:

```
dict1 = {'abc': {'test1': 123}}
dict2 = {'abc': 100}
```

produces (as expected):

```
{'abc': 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a dictionary in a dictionary und you want to update the inner dictionary with the inner dictionary of the other one. So you have to apply the update method to the inner dictionary:

```py
dict1["abc"].update(dict2["abc"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

merge = defaultdict(dict)

# Handle nesting
for d in [dict1, dict2]:
    for k0, v0 in d.items():
        for k1, v1 in v0.items():
            merge[k0][k1] = v1  # Assign to defaultdict
print(dict(merge))  # -> {'abc': {'test1': 123, 'test2': 456}}
```

Or you could use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

```
merge = {}

for d in [dict1, dict2]:
    for k0, v0 in d.items():
        merge.setdefault(k0, {})
        for k1, v1 in v0.items():
            merge[k0][k1] = v1
print(merge)  # -> {'abc': {'test1': 123, 'test2': 456}}
```