# What data structure acts like a dictionary and supports multuiple values per key?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have player and uniform data. Player name is the key, uniform number is the value. A player may wear multiple uniform numbers over their career.

```
{"Michael Jordan":45}
{"Michael Jordan":23}
```

This won't work because the second entry replaces the first:

```
myData = {}
myData["Michael Jordan"] = 45
myData["Michael Jordan"] = 23
```

I can't store that in a dictionary. What data structure should be used?

Comment: `{"Michael Jordan": [45, 23]}` OR maybe `{("Michael Jordan", 1990): 45, ("Michael Jordan", 1992): 23}`

Comment: could you put the values to a list and then assign them to the key?

Comment: A custom class whose `__setitem__` method automatically accumulates values could be written, but then it's not obvious when assignment can replace a value or when values are accumulated. Better to store and use a container like a list explicitly.

Comment: @d.b or continuing on that line, `{'Michael Jordan': {1990: 45, 1992: 23}}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have a dictionary with same-name keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813564/can-i-have-a-dictionary-with-same-name-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dict of lists or a dict of sets is a pretty common structure, to have more than one value per key.

```py
data = [('Michael Jordan', 45), ('Kobe Bryant', 8), ('Michael Jordan', 23), ('Kobe Bryant', 24), ('Michael Jordan', 23)]

d = {}
for player, uniform in data:
    if player not in d:
        d[player] = [uniform]
    else:
        d[player].append(uniform)
```

Personally I don't like the `if / else` in that loop. You can get rid of it using the default value of `dict.get`, or using `dict.setdefault`, or using a `defaultdict`:

```py
# 1ST METHOD: DICT.GET WITH DEFAULT VALUE
d = {}
for player, uniform in data:
    d[player] = d.get(player, [])
    d[player].append(uniform)

# 2ND METHOD: DICT.SETDEFAULT
d = {}
for player, uniform in data:
    d.setdefault(player, []).append(uniform)

# 3RD METHOD: DEFAULTDICT
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for player, uniform in data:
    d[player].append(uniform)
```

In all cases, the result is the same:

```py
# 1st and 2nd methods
print(d)
# {'Michael Jordan': [45, 23, 23], 'Kobe Bryant': [8, 24]}

# 3rd method
print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Michael Jordan': [45, 23, 23], 'Kobe Bryant': [8, 24]})
```

However, perhaps we don't like this duplicate value `23` in Michael Jordan's uniforms. If we don't care about the order of the values, but we care about getting rid of duplicates, then the go-to data structure we need is a `set`, not a `list`.

Our 4 possible methods become:

```py
d = {}
for player, uniform in data:
    if player not in d:
        d[player] = {uniform}
    else:
        d[player].add(uniform)

# 1ST METHOD: DICT.GET WITH DEFAULT VALUE
d = {}
for player, uniform in data:
    d[player] = d.get(player, set())
    d[player].add(uniform)

# 2ND METHOD: DICT.SETDEFAULT
d = {}
for player, uniform in data:
    d.setdefault(player, set()).add(uniform)

# 3RD METHOD: DEFAULTDICT
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
for player, uniform in data:
    d[player].add(uniform)

# RESULT

# 1st and 2nd methods
print(d)
# {'Michael Jordan': {45, 23}, 'Kobe Bryant': {8, 24}}

# 3rd method
print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'Michael Jordan': {45, 23}, 'Kobe Bryant': {8, 24}})
```

Finally, I'd like to show one more method, which is to use [function `map_reduce`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.map_reduce) from [module `more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/):

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from more_itertools import map_reduce

# DICT OF LIST
d = map_reduce(data, keyfunc=itemgetter(0), valuefunc=itemgetter(1))
print(d)
# defaultdict(None, {'Michael Jordan': [45, 23, 23], 'Kobe Bryant': [8, 24]})

# DICT OF SET
d = map_reduce(data, keyfunc=itemgetter(0), valuefunc=itemgetter(1), reducefunc=set)
print(d)
# defaultdict(None, {'Michael Jordan': {45, 23}, 'Kobe Bryant': {8, 24}})
```